Amplify Hosting React app with express node js backend
0
I have react JS as my client side framework and Node JS express is my API backend services with Dynamodb so Both are working fine on my local but with amplify the frontend is working well but the api call is not working So I'm confused does amplify support NODEjs,
I want my db data to be fetch by amplify domain as well.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
